Finding porosity using Ideal gas law
A 1 $cm^3$ sample or reservoir rock is put in a chamber of 10 $cm^3$, where the total pressure is 750 $mmHg$. This chamber is closed, and a valve is opened such that the air can expand to another chamber previously in a vacuum, which volume is also 10 $cm^3$. The final pressure in the two chambers is 361.4 $mmHg$.
To calculate the effective porosity of this sample, we assume that the sample has a volume of solid rock ($V_s$) and a volume of interconnected empty spaces (V_p), and that temperature doesn't change when the valve is opened. Using $P_iV_i=P_fV_f$ we have:
$$750(10-V_s)=361.4(20-V_s)$$ then $V_s=0.7$, where $V_p=V-V_s=1-V_s=0.3$, and porosity is $\phi=\frac{V_p}{V}=0.3=30\%$
Now, my book asks:
If the second chamber wasn't previously in a vacuum, but instead had a pressure of 10.2 $mmHg$, what would be the porosity of the sample?
I can't solve this, seems like too many unknowns, the answer is $\phi=0.038=3.8\%$.

In the second case, is the final pressure still 361.4 mmHg and volume of the second chamber 10 cm3?

p1V1 + p2V2 = p3V3 // Be aware that many literal numerical values have units that should be used explicitly. While it can be – by a bad habit – ignored in trivial cases, it can cause headache in complex ones.
